# Preselect first in stock product variation woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’d like to preselect the first product variation that is in stock if no default is set.

Currently I’m using this code [Automatically pre-select first in stock value in WooCommerce variable product dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70935529/automatically-pre-select-first-in-stock-value-in-woocommerce-variable-product-dr) and it almost works but if the variations have been rearranged it breaks as the indexs no longer match up with the variations

Answer (score 2):

Managed to modify the above code I was using to find the solution

```
    function filter_woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args( $args ) {

    // Check the count of available options in dropdown
    if ( count( $args['options'] ) > 0 ) {
        // Initialize
        $options = array();
        // Get WC_Product_Variable Object
        $product = $args['product'];
        $has_default = count($product->get_default_attributes());
        if(!$has_default) {
            // Is a WC Product Variable
            if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product_Variable' ) ) {
                // Get an array of available variations for the current product
                foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $key => $variation ) {
                    // Is in stock
                    $is_in_stock = $variation['is_in_stock'];
                    $attributes = $variation['attributes'];
                    // True
                    if ( $is_in_stock ) {
                        // Set key
                        foreach ( $attributes as $key => $attribute ) {
                            array_push($options, $attribute);
                        }
                        // Break
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Finds whether a variable is a number
            if ( count( $options ) > 0 ) {
                // Selected
                $option_key = "";
                foreach ( $options as $key => $option ) {
                    $i = 0;
                    while($i < count($args['options'])) {
                        if($option == $args['options'][$i]) {
                            $option_key = $i;
                            // break;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                    // break;
                }
                $args['selected'] = $args['options'][$option_key];
            } else {
                $args['selected'] = "";
            }
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'filter_woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 10, 1 );
```